# Scroll a div horizontally in an other div

Tags: jquery, html, horizontal-scrolling

I want to reproduce this (which work perfectly) :

http://jsfiddle.net/PvVdq/

But I don't want it to apply on document.height, only on my div height.

this is the script I have

```
if(positionYDiapo<=middleHeight){

        $('#frame').css({position:'fixed', top: positionTop - $(window).scrollTop(), bottom:'auto'}).addClass('stuck').removeClass('anchored');


            if(bottomDiapo<=bottomFrame){
                $('#frame').css({ 'position': 'absolute' });
                $('#frame').css({ 'bottom': '0px' });
                $('#frame').css({ 'top': 'auto' });
                $('#frame').removeClass('stuck').addClass('anchored');
            }

            var $horizontal = $('#frame');

            var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
                d = $(document).height(),
                c = $(this).height();

            scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

            var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - $horizontal.width()));

            $horizontal.css({'left': position});    


       var st = $(this).scrollTop();
       if (st > lastScrollTop){
           // downscroll code
           console.log('down');
       } else {
          // upscroll code

          if((bottomFrame)-hauteurDiv>=middleHeight){
             console.log('up');
             $('#frame').css({position:'fixed', top: positionTop - $(window).scrollTop(), bottom:'auto'}).addClass('stuck').removeClass('anchored');

           }
       }
       lastScrollTop = st;  


    }else{
        console.log('no code here');
        $('#frame').css({position:'absolute', top:'0px', bottom:'auto'}).removeClass('stuck').removeClass('anchored');
    }
```

Plus, I need to keep track of the left position for when the action stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to change everything that was first referenced to the document to a `div` you would like the scroll to apply to.

JavaScript has two very handy functions for determining widths and lengths called:

- [element.scrollHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollHeight)
- [element.scrollWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollWidth)

You can implement these functions in jQuery by altering your function something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $horizontal = $('#horizontal');

    $('#test').scroll(function () {
        var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
            d = $('#test').get(0).scrollHeight,
            c = $('#test').get(0).scrollWidth,

        scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

        var position = (scrollPercent * (c - 2*$horizontal.width()));

        $horizontal.css({
            'left': position
        });
    });
});
```

(I didn't check if the calculations were absolutely correct so you might want to look into that)

With the corresponding HTML structure:

```
<div id="test">

// put your content here

</div>

<div id="horizontal">scrolling div</div>
```

You can find an implementation of that code [in this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msBVf/).

I hope that gets you started. Good luck!